# Class org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader can not access a member of class with modifiers "public static"

Tags: java

When I run jar from the command line, I get this exception. How to find the error? Eclipse doesn't show any errors in the code.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader can not access a member of class main.FirefoxServer with modifiers "public static"
        at sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.slowCheckMemberAccess(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkAccess(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is most likely that your class containing the `main` method is declared with the wrong modifiers. Check this and most likely the problem will be resolved.
Here's an example of a properly designed class with a main method:

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Write your code here
    }
}
```